# I have a column called Gender, how can I count male and female group by division

Tags: sql, group-by, counting

I have a column called Gender, how can I count male and female group by division

Here is my Table:

| ID | Name | Gender | Division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jose Rizal | Male | Manila |
| 2 | Maria Clara | Female | Cebu |
| 3 | Brando Hervala | Male | Cebu |
| 4 | Sampurna Makabi | Male | Manila |

Output expectation :

| Division | Total Male | Total Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manila | 2 | 0 |
| Cebu | 1 | 1 |

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT
     Division
    ,(
        Select
            COUNT(Gender)
        from Table
        where gender = 'Male'
     ) as 'Total Male'
    ,(
        Select
            COUNT(Gender)
        from Table
        where gender = 'Female'
     ) as 'Total Female'
FROM Table
GROUP by Division
```

Comment: what's this got to do with C# [there's no C# in your question].  WRT to your question - you could try doing something like this - `SELECT Division, Gender, Count(*) AS GenderCount GROUP BY Division, Gender` - then you can use that result as the sub-query for others..

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Division
    , SUM(case when Gender = 'Male' then 1 end) as 'Total Male'
    , SUM(case when Gender = 'Female'then 1 end) as 'Total Female'
FROM Table
GROUP by Division
```

Comment: I'd add `else 0` to the case expressions, to get 0 instead of null for non-existing values.